# linux i2c module incomplete xfer (0x48) error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, i2c

I am working i2c Device connected to A13 embedded linux.I tried to just get data from register but always get incomplete xfer (0x48) error.i found the error code in i2c-sunxi.c file.

```
case 0x48: /* SLA+R has been transmitted; NOT ACK has been received */
err_code = 0x48;//err,wakeup the thread
```

my i2c module function is;

```
unsigned char buf[1] = { 0 };

struct i2c_msg msgs[] = {
{ this_client->addr, 0, 1, buf },   /* setup read ptr */
{ this_client->addr, I2C_M_RD, 1, buf },    /* read status + date */
};

/* read registers */
if ((i2c_transfer(this_client->adapter, msgs, 2)) != 2) {
dev_err(&this_client->dev, "%s: read error\n", __func__);
return -EIO;
}
```

Comment: Can you see any devices on the I2C bus?  What is the I2C address of the device on the bus?

Answer (score 1):

Try `i2cdetect` and `i2cget` from  `i2c-tools` package, it is known to do things right. If it fails too, the device misbehaves. Try to ask this in LKML, you might event send a patch, if it's legal.

BTW, are you sure you need a [combined transfer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-i2c-transfer.html)? Maybe separate read and write would do the thing?

And `xfer` is a [SMBus-related term](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/i2c.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply.but i have to do i2c process in kernel module.i wrote a driver for my device but i cannot connect i2c because of this error.I am not sure use i2c_transfer().but i also tried i2c_master_send() function.